# How do you chain multiple functions, and return multiple tuples from each one?

Tags: python, function, chaining

I'm trying to write a program that contains numerous functions for different calculations, all of them involving tuples, and being controlled by a main()

the functions are essentially this:

```
def open_file()
def read_file()
def get_data()
def calculate_info()
def display_info()

def main()
    open_file()
    read_file()
    get_data()
    calculate_info()
    display_info()

main()
```

What confuses me is how to chain them together. For example, I want the read_file() to read what open_file() returned, get_data() to get what I want from what read_file() returned, etc.

My question is then what should actually be returned and how do I make sure the next function uses what the previous one returned? Related to that, what goes in the parentheses?

Comment: This is pretty broad relating to variable assignation and returning things from functions, and I'm sure it's a duplicate.

Comment: so you should figure out how to pass a single argument to a single function and build up from there. maybe something like this will help: http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/functions.html

Comment: Do you mean like `open_file().read_file().get_data()...`?

Comment: I'm sure it's a duplicate; I've seen some similar questions. But I'm pretty new at this, and the concepts are clicking, so a similar question is tough for me to completely follow. I'll check out some of the links posted.

Comment: More like, open_file() gives me a product called "a." read_file() reads "a" and gives me "b." get_data() takes "b" and gives me "c" etc. Does that make any sense? I'm happy to clarify anything!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this to process tuples in python

```
def open_file(*file):
    return ("test", "test2")

def read_file(*file):
    return ("test", "test2") 

def get_data(data1, data2):
    return ("test", "test2")

def calculate_info(*data):
    return (8, 10, 14)

def display_info(*data):
    print data

def main()
    (k,l) = open_file()
    (m,n) = read_file(k,l)
    (o,p) = get_data(m,n)
    (q,r,s) = calculate_info(o,p)
    display_info(q,r,s)

main()
```

You use the * operator to specify a tuple as a parameter in python. When returning return a tuple, and keep them either as a single variable like
 x = open_file()

or
 (p,q) = open_file()

Comment: This looks similar to what I'm trying to do! I'll play around with some stuff this way!

Answer (score 1):

One option is to keep a reference of the functions and call them within a loop. For example:

```
def foo(x):
    return x+1

def bar(x):
    return x+2

funcs = [foo, bar]
a = 0

for f in funcs:
    a = f(a)
print(a)
```

If you need more control, have a look at the [command-pattern](http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/FunctionObjects.html#command-choosing-the-operation-at-runtime).